# What is the word for "event executor"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

If a company runs a service as "one who arranges, holds, and executes planned events", what's the term of it? "Events executor" seems a rather grim name, "Events arranger" seems lack of fume because what the company does is more than just arrange for the event. They basically oversee the whole thing from the start (planning) to the end (cleaning up and deliver the certificates if any).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're talking about an *event manager* or *event planner*.

From Wikipedia's article on [*event management*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_management) (redirected from *event planner*):

> The process of planning and coordinating the event is usually referred to as **event planning** and which can include budgeting, scheduling, site selection, acquiring necessary permits, coordinating transportation and parking, arranging for speakers or entertainers, arranging decor, event security, catering, coordinating with third party vendors, and emergency plans. Each event is different in its nature so process of planning & execution of each event differs on basis of type of event.
>
> The **event manager** is the person who plans and executes the event, taking responsibility for the creative, technical, and logistical elements. This includes overall event design, brand building, marketing and communication strategy, audio-visual production, script writing, logistics, budgeting, negotiation, and client service.

From ["Becoming an Event Planner"](https://www.thebalancesmb.com/what-is-an-event-planner-1223579) at The Balance Small Business:

> The event planner creates programs that address the purpose, message or impression that their organization or client is trying to communicate. Event planners work long and non-traditional hours to plan and execute all details related to a variety of meeting formats including seminars, conferences, trade shows, executive retreats, incentive programs, golf events, conventions, and other programs.

Comment: Definitely "event *planner*".

Comment: The term "event organizer" is more familiar in my ears, but I think from definition-wise, "event management" is a more correct term in this case.

Comment: @RonJohn As a British English speaker, I would say 'definitely "event *manager*" '.  I can work out what an event planner does, but I've not heard it.

Answer (score 8):

Interesting question. I am a native English speaker and I come across situations like this all of the time; they are very common! There is no one correct way to answer this, but here I would probably use “event organizer.” However, if this term still seems too vague, adding additional context can help the reader understand what kind of service you are referring to.

Comment: Ah! Event *organizer*! That's the word I'm looking for. Thanks!!

Comment: An organizer is a person who orchestrates an event; the OP is asking for what to call a company which manages events, for which *event manager* or *event planner* as Jason Bassford suggests would be better in my opinion.

Comment: I agree. A hasty response on my part.

Comment: @choster Don't forget "event coordinator".  I think "planner" is a bit more common, but that may be skewed by the prominence of "wedding planner", while other events may use different terms.

Comment: Can you help explain what is the difference between orchestrates an event with 
manages an event? @choster

Comment: @ChenLiYong *Event organizer* is the most generic term. I would be the organizer if I arranged a cookout with friends, or a concert outing. I would distinguish a professional who does it with other terms, depending on the role. If I rent out a ballroom at a hotel for a party, the hotel will likely have an *event planner* who will arrange for the catering, lighting, setup and cleanup, decorations, and so forth. At the actual event, the same person or some other staff member will be supervising the affair so all goes as planned, and I would call that person the *event manager*.

Answer (score 4):

Event coordinator:

> What exactly does an event coordinator do? 
>   Day-to-day duties often depend on where an event coordinator works and what needs to get done.
>   In general, an event coordinator puts together events, tackling anything from client meetings to cleanup. Responsibilities may include preparing budgets, scouting and booking locations, conducting press outreach, lining up sponsors and celebrity guests, and securing food and drinks.

https://www.mediabistro.com/climb-the-ladder/skills-expertise/what-does-an-event-coordinator-do/

Comment: Event coordinator. Never heard of this phrase, but sounds great. I definitely can use this for future references. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use **event host**. Hosting differs from event *organizing* or *planning*, in that it stresses that they provide the location and are responsible for the party. It is not 100% precise which sense it refers to though (these correspond to 1b and 1a in the definition below). You would likely want to combine it with planning or organizing, as in:

> We can **organize and host** events of up to 200 people.

The applicable definitions of host from Merriam-Webster:

> **host** noun (2)
>
> 1a : one that receives or entertains
>   guests socially, commercially, or officially
>   1b : one that provides facilities for an event or function
>
> **host** verb (2) hosted; hosting; hosts
>   *transitive verb*
>
> 1 : to receive or entertain guests at or for 
>     : to serve as host (see host entry 3 sense 1a)

<sup>*Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/host*</sup>

Comment: In my past understanding, "host" is referring more to (a) person than (a) company. Like a host of a talk show, or a host of a party. Learn something new from this. Thanks!